# What are the formats supported by MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, codec, formats

Which formats does MPMoviePlayerController Support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW20):

### Supported Formats

This class plays any movie or audio file supported in iOS. This includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:

- H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
- MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)

If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.

Comment: Where can I find a specific list of supported video playback resolutions?